# Show Current URL in popover window - Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, html, safari-extension

I'm trying to create a very basic Safari extension that shows the current tab's URL in the popover once you click on the toolbar icon.

I have the following code so far:

**global.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="global.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**global.js:**

```
function getCurrentURL() {
    return safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
}
```

**popover.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="popover.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bodyContainer" id="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popover.js**

```
var main = function() {
    var currentURL = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getCurrentURL();
    console.debug("TTLogs: Current URL in Popover: " + currentURL);
    modifyBody(currentURL);
};

var modifyBody = function(link) {
    var body = document.getElementById("status");
    body.innerHTML = "Hello world. Link is " + link; // I get error here. body is returned as null.
};

main();
```

What I want is, when I click on the popover icon, I want the popover to show *"Hello world. Link is ".*

What actually happens is when I click on the popover icon, in the console, I see that I am getting the correct URL however, I'm getting the error:

```
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'body.innerHTML = "Hello world. Link is " + link')modifyBody (popover.js:9)
```

The idea of the extension is when I click on the popover, it needs to:

1. Fetch the current tab's URL.
2. Do some magic analysis on it.
3. Display the results in the popover.html dynamically (through DOM manipulation).

What am I missing here?

**EDIT** I solved it.
The expected flow I wanted was:

1. Make a call to `global.js` to capture the URL of the page
2. Wait for response from `global.js`
3. Once the response is received, update the `popover.html` with the URL

The flow that actually was taking place was:

1. Make a call to `global.js` to capture the URL of the page
2. Immediately call `modifyBody()` with empty content (since we haven't received response from global.js yet). So the page remains blank.
3. Finally receive a response from `global.js` - but it's too late now.

To fix that, I had multiple options. Couple of the options are:

1. Use promises to wait to update the popover.html once we receive a response from `global.js`
2. OR, create a `popoverHandler` and add it to the event listener like this:

   `safari.application.addEventListener("popover", popoverHandler, true);`

This will be called right when you click on the toolbar item and right when the popover is being displayed.

So the code looks like this:

```
var popoverHandler = function(event) {
    console.debug("Opening popup. Identifier");
    var currentURL = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getURL();
    // update my page.html here.
};
```

You can also register `"activate"`, `"open"` or `"navigate"` handlers in `global.js` - and then call `popover.js` update html function to once those are triggered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access actual page context from within the global page – I guess Safari prevents you to do so. You can access the global page from bars and popovers but not from actual page.

Use messaging instead, see e.g. [Support Logic for Injected Scripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH16-SW8) in Extensions tutorial. You'll need two simple functions for asking URL and returning its value.

Comment: No, that's not it. I am updating ONLY the popover.html from popover.js - and it wasn't working. I found the problem and I'm editing my Question to add that.

Comment: OK, sounds good. Still, you could use messaging too – maybe you'd have to if you'd need to inject code into actual page at the very same time. Thanks for update.